# Whitelist self-signed SSL CA certificate without aliases

Tags: java, ssl

We have a WildFly server, that issues certificates for the HTTPS connection. It's turned out that the certificate has no any aliases. All the fields under "Subject Name" and "Issuer Name" are "Unknown". The same for the Root CA certificate we downloaded from server in order to add the CA into trusted CA using java keytool. The certification path is "unknown", and the issuer has

```
CN = Unknown
OU = Unknown
O = Unknown
L = Unknown
S = Unknown
C = Unknown
```

Is there any way to whitelist such hostname and perform secure TLS connection without disabling the SSL at all? How can I add such a CA Root certificate into java keystore if there are no aliases and I'm still getting the "no aliases for the certificate" error whet trying to connect to the server afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Found one temporary solution. We have just to add

```
1.2.3.4 Unknown
```

to the Hosts file in the system. And then access the server by https://Unknown url.